# Mi vista de javafx no levanta desde el lado de netbeans

Tags: java, sql-server, javafx, netbeans-8.2

Estoy creando un proyecto desde Netbeans, javaFx y SQLServer.
Mi problema es que cree una vista desde el lado de javaFx y luego le hice las configuraciones(Agregar Controlador,Identificar los objetos y asignar los eventos), pero cuando ejecute el proyecto de Netbeans me abre la ventana principal pero la ventana Tallas no

```
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import org.jhonylopez.sistema.Principal; 
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MenuPrincipalController implements Initializable{
    private Principal escenarioPrincipal;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }

    public Principal getEscenarioPrincipal() {
        return escenarioPrincipal;
    }

    public void setEscenarioPrincipal(Principal escenarioPrincipal) {
        this.escenarioPrincipal = escenarioPrincipal;
    }

    public void ventanaCategoria(){
        escenarioPrincipal.ventanaCategorias();
    }

    public void ventanaMarca()
    {
        escenarioPrincipal.ventanaMarcas();
    }

    public void ventanaTalla()
    {
        escenarioPrincipal.ventanaTallas();
    }
}
```

A continuacion esta el codigo de la clase Principal

```
public class Principal extends Application {
    private final String PAQUETE_VISTA = "/org/jhonylopez/view/" ;
    private Stage escenarioPrincipal;
    private Scene escena;
    @Override

    public void start(Stage escenarioPrincipal) {
        this.escenarioPrincipal = escenarioPrincipal;
        escenarioPrincipal.setTitle("NextSport");
        menuPrincipal();
        escenarioPrincipal.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void menuPrincipal(){
        try{
            MenuPrincipalController menuPrincipal = (MenuPrincipalController)cambiarEscena("MenuPrincipalView.fxml", 400, 400);
            menuPrincipal.setEscenarioPrincipal(this);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void ventanaCategorias()
    {
        try{
            CategoriaController categoriaController = (CategoriaController) cambiarEscena("CategoriaView.fxml", 600, 470);
            categoriaController.setEscenarioPrincipal(this);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public void ventanaMarcas()
    {
        try{
            MarcaController marcaController = (MarcaController) cambiarEscena("MarcaView.fxml", 600, 470);
            marcaController.setEscenarioPrincipal(this);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public void ventanaTallas()
    {
        try
        {
            TallaController tallaController = (TallaController) cambiarEscena("TallaView", 600, 470);
            tallaController.setEscenarioPrincipal(this);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public Initializable cambiarEscena(String fxml, int ancho, int alto) throws Exception{
        Initializable resultado = null;
        FXMLLoader cargadorFXML = new FXMLLoader();
        InputStream archivo = Principal.class.getResourceAsStream(PAQUETE_VISTA + fxml);
        cargadorFXML.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
        cargadorFXML.setLocation(Principal.class.getResource(PAQUETE_VISTA));
        escena = new Scene((AnchorPane)cargadorFXML.load(archivo),ancho,alto);
        escenarioPrincipal.setScene(escena);
        escenarioPrincipal.sizeToScene();
        resultado = (Initializable) cargadorFXML.getController();
        return resultado;
    }

}
```

Hice una prueba con un breakPoint pero no entra a la siguiente linea:

```
TallaController tallaController = (TallaController) cambiarEscena("TallaView", 600, 470);
        tallaController.setEscenarioPrincipal(this);
```

Comment: Y no te muestra por consola ningún error??

Comment: Cambia esta línea `e.getMessage();` por algo como esto `e.printStackTrace();` para que puedas ver el la traza de la excepción que se debe estar lanzando.

Comment: Ya coloque `e.printStackTrace();` y el error dice java.lang.NullPointerException: inputStream is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se produce porque no se encuentra el archivo FXML de la vista de JavaFX. Cuando haces esta llamada

```
cambiarEscena("TallaView", 600, 470);
```

te falta incluir la extensión `.fxml` al nombre del archivo

```
cambiarEscena("TallaView.fxml", 600, 470);
```

Por eso, cuando se ejecuta esta línea del método `cambiarEscene()`,

```
InputStream archivo = Principal.class.getResourceAsStream(PAQUETE_VISTA + fxml);
```

retorna `null`, y al intentar manipular posteriormente la variable `archivo` ocurre un `NullPointerException`

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte @E.Betanzos, a la próxima tendré más atención a esos detalles

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta márcala como correcta. Saludos